# How to remove certain values from an array, that does not meet a criteria?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, loops, vector

If i have an array that consist of numbers numbers, say

```
A = [1.3, 2.2, 2.3,4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1,1.1, 5.2, 3.1]
```

I would like to extract the numbers that only where the integer is in the array and .1,.2 and .3 comes after. E.g i would not like to include 1 in my new array because 1.2 does not exist in A. I would like to include 5 though, since both 5.1,5.2 and 5.3 is in A. How can i go about this? MatLab or Python answers accepted!

EDIT**
Thank you. I realize now, that i might have asked the wrong question, instead of printing the integers which have the decimals .1,.2,.3 i want the final array to consist of the floats from A, but only the floats that have both .1,.2,.3 behind the same integer. Sorry!

Comment: Is this about Python or Matlab?

Comment: i will be happy about an answer in either language.

Comment: It is helpful if you add the expected output matrix  in your questions

Comment: Will do! in this example it is supposed to be

out = [2.2 ,2.3 ,2.1 ,3.1 ,3.2 ,3.3 ,5.1 ,5.2  ,5,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **MATLAB** (may not the best algorithm):

```
clc; clear;

tolerance = 10^(-15);
% Tolerance is useful in order to compare arrays, because the "==" operator
% can lean to wrong results.

% The fractional parts we are interested in.
desirable_list = [0.1 0.2 0.3];

% Because we are going to work with ordered lists, we order the
% desirable_list as well.
desirable = sort(desirable_list, 'ascend');

% Our list and the sorted list.
A = [1.3, 2.2, 2.3, 4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1, 1.1, 5.2, 3.1];
A_sorted = sort(A);

% Getting the integer parts (uniquely) of our list.
integer_parts = unique(fix(A));

% Getting the elements that satisfy our criteria in an ordered list in an
% array called S.
S = [];
for j = integer_parts
    m1 = (A_sorted(fix(A_sorted) == j));
    if m1 < 0
        m1 = sort(m1, 'descend');
    end


    if length(m1) == length(desirable) & abs(abs(m1) - desirable) < abs(j) + tolerance
        S = [S m1];
    end
end

% Getting the elements we are interested in, in the specific order they
% appear in our original list.

V = zeros(1,length(S));
l = 1;
for k = 1:length(A)
    if ismember(A(k), S)
        V(l)= A(k);
        l = l + 1;
    end
end
A
V
```

**Output:**

```
A =

    1.3000    2.2000    2.3000    4.2000    5.1000    3.2000    5.3000    3.3000    2.1000    1.1000    5.2000    3.1000


V =

    2.2000    2.3000    5.1000    3.2000    5.3000    3.3000    2.1000    5.2000    3.1000

>>
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize now, that i might have asked the wrong question, instead of printing the integers which have the decimals .1,.2,.3 i want the final array to consist of the floats from A, but only the floats that have both .1,.2,.3 behind the same integer. Sorry!

Comment: Is there any way so that the output S returns the values in the same order as they were in A? E.g with A 
S = [2.2000    2.3000    5.1000    3.2000    5.3000...]

Comment: Damn, thanks a lot! Learn something new all the time

Answer (score 0):

In **Python**, you can do:

```
import operator

A = [1.3, 2.2, 2.3,4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1,1.1, 5.2, 3.1]

s = set(int(str(i).split('.')[0]) for i in A)

res = []
for n in s:
    if all(x in A for x in map(operator.add, [n, n, n], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3])):
        res.append(n)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[2, 3, 5]
```

**Edit:**

If what you want is to get floats that have .1, .2 and .3 behind the same integer, try the following:

```
for n in s:
    temp = map(operator.add, [n, n, n], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
    if all(x in A for x in temp):
        res.extend(temp)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3]
```

Comment: The condition is too weak : it would match `[1.1,1.1,1.1]`

Comment: @EricDuminil, You're right, I just fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using **Python** you can do:

```
import numpy as np
A = [1.3, 2.2, 2.3, 4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1, 1.1, 5.2, 3.1]
b = set([int(i) for i in A if np.all([j in A for j in (np.array([1, 2, 3]) + 10*int(np.floor(i)))/10.0])])
```

where b is

```
set([2, 3, 5])
```

(which can easily be converted into a list using `list`).

**Comments**:

I multiply by `10` and divide by `10.0` to try to avoid floating point arithmetic issues. It is not clear in the question if you want the comparison to be numeric or string based.

Answer (score 0):

With Python, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the floats by their trucated value, and check that the decimals are a superset of [1,2,3] :

```
from itertools import groupby
needed_decimals = set([1, 2, 3])

a = [1.3, 2.2, 2.3,4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1,1.1, 5.2, 3.1]

pairs = [tuple(int(y) for y in str(x).split('.')) for x in sorted(a)]
#=> [(1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)]
integers = [integer for integer, numbers in groupby(pairs, lambda x: x[0]) if set(x[1] for x in numbers) >= needed_decimals]
#=> [2,3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

A MATLAB solution:(updated because of an update in the question)

```
A = [1.3, 2.2, 2.3,4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1,1.1, 5.2, 3.1]
INC = [.1 .2 .3];
F = floor(A);
U = unique(F,'stable');
%find unique  values of F
B = bsxfun(@plus,U,INC.');
%with broadcasting sum each element with [.1 .2 .3]
%in MATLAB R2016b you can write B = U + INC.';
IDX = all(ismember(B,A));
%for each integer I if  I+[.1 .2 .3] exist in the array return index of it
OUT =B(:,IDX);
%extract output
```

A more compact form:

```
B = bsxfun(@plus,unique(floor(A),'stable'),INC.');
OUT = B(:,all(ismember(B,A)))
```

that in MATLAB R2016b or Octave can be written as:

```
B = unique(floor(A),'stable') + INC.';
OUT = B(:, all(ismember(B,A)))
```

Result

```
OUT =

   2.1000   3.1000   5.1000
   2.2000   3.2000   5.2000
   2.3000   3.3000   5.3000
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize now, that i might have asked the wrong question, instead of printing the integers which have the decimals .1,.2,.3 i want the final array to consist of the floats from A, but only the floats that have both .1,.2,.3 behind the same integer. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

**set([x for x in map(int,l) if all([float(str(x)+'.' + str(e)) in l for e in [1,2,3]])])**

does the trick in one line